# curl giving an empty response

Tags: curl, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I'am running an curl command to disable the spring-boot loggers

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST -d '{}' http://10.97.65.59:9191/myApplication/actuator/loggers/com.path.to.the.class
```

after running the api, the logger's are disabled but i don't see any content , it just gives a new empty new line, not event the status code . how can i get the status code??

when running in postman i get `204 : no content` response.

Comment: To fetch the status line you should add the -i flag to your request.